# Shopify app generating a shopify api token "This request is NOT from Shopify!"

Tags: shopify

I have been following the [shopify documentation](https://www.shopify.com/partners/blog/17056443-how-to-generate-a-shopify-api-token) for generating a shopify api token.

Here is my code for **install.php**

```
<?php

// Set variables for our request
$shop = "ecommerce-52";
$api_key = "6bdad749dxxxx24c462c7d2af";
$scopes = "read_orders,write_products";
$redirect_uri = "http://localhost/shopify/shopify-generating-api-token-guide/generate_token.php";
//$redirect_uri = "https://ecommerce-52.myshopify.com";

// Build install/approval URL to redirect to
$install_url = "https://" . $shop . ".myshopify.com/admin/oauth/authorize?client_id=" . $api_key . "&scope=" . $scopes . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($redirect_uri);

//print_r($install_url);
// Redirect
header("Location: " . $install_url);
die();
```

It redirects me to the install app page, after i click install i'm redirected to

```
http://localhost/shopify/shopify-generating-api-token-guide/generate_token.php?code=86f5027cxxxxxxxxx9c5d&hmac=fcf1e1bexxxxxxxxa97b0f79ec1ec7b473e0bc36bf71&shop=ecommerce-52.myshopify.com&signature=12a6ab63c04d9844ff6xxxxxx0&timestamp=1458991225
```

But it says:

```
This request is NOT from Shopify!
```

Here is my code for generate_token.php

```js
<?php

// Get our helper functions
require_once("inc/functions.php");

// Set variables for our request
$shop = "ecommerce-52";
$api_key = "6bdad749xxxxxxx24c462c7d2af";
$shared_secret = "c679xxxxx3ac11474599";
$code = $_GET["code"];
$timestamp = $_GET["timestamp"];
$signature = $_GET["signature"];

// Compile signature data
$signature_data = $shared_secret . "code=" . $code . "shop=". $shop . ".myshopify.comtimestamp=" . $timestamp;

// Use signature data to check that the response is from Shopify or not
if (md5($signature_data) === $signature) {

    // Set variables for our request
    $query = array(
        "Content-type" => "application/json", // Tell Shopify that we're expecting a response in JSON format
        "client_id" => $api_key, // Your API key
        "client_secret" => $shared_secret, // Your app credentials (secret key)
        "code" => $code // Grab the access key from the URL
    );

    // Call our Shopify function
    $shopify_response = shopify_call(NULL, $shop, "/admin/oauth/access_token", $query, 'POST');

    // Convert response into a nice and simple array
    $shopify_response = json_decode($shopify_response['response'], TRUE);

    // Store the response
    $token = $shopify_response['access_token'];

    // Show token (DO NOT DO THIS IN YOUR PRODUCTION ENVIRONMENT)
    echo $token;

} else {
    // Someone is trying to be shady!
    die('This request is NOT from Shopify!');
}
```

I can't figure out whats is it that i'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

**Update:**

I've even tried deploying it on Heroku (That is https by default),  but still no luck. I can't understand why my values for `$signature` and `$md5($signature_data)` are not same.

Comment: Can you provide the values of md5($signature_data) and $signature

Comment: from the generate_token.php ?

Comment: Yes I was wondering if there's something simple like one is null or they are in different formats.

Comment: Here is $signature:
71d19a747d5f3d83e251f07cdce04863

And here is md5($signature_data): 14aa379906b3a67f4b97ef4761c5a469

Comment: I haven't changed anything in the sample code except the credentials.

Comment: Sure, so the only thing I can think of left is to double check that *your* shared key is the same in shopify as it is in your code.

Comment: You click on show secret and it displays a key in Credential sets, if that is the secret key then yes its correct one.

Comment: In the if condition we are checking if md5($signature_data) and $signature are equal and identical, but as you can see that are not, is that why its not executing the if part?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107404/discussion-between-daniel-james-bryars-and-subhan-ahmed).

Answer (score 0):

So you are building a hash which includes a shared key. This provides a guarantee that the values of $code, $shop and $timestamp haven't been tampered with and that the request came from someone who has your shared key.

So I can think of the following scenarios which would lead to this:

1. $shared_secret, $code, $shop, $timestamp have been tampered with
   (unlikely)
2. The method to calculate the hash is wrong -
   $signature_data = $shared_secret . "code=" . $code . "shop=". $shop
   . ".myshopify.comtimestamp=" . $timestamp; (unlikely if it's example
   code)
3. The md5 on your client is broken (unlikely)
4. BTW I'm surprised you don't need to base64 encode somewhere. (unlikely if
   you haven't changed the sample code)
5. Your $shared_secret is
   different (that's what I would check first)

Comment: I have not changed anything in the sample code except for the shop, api_key and shared secret.. For the rest i'm following the routine.

First browse to install.php >> then we get the approve page >> then it redirects to the generate_token page that is where i get the error

Comment: That method is exactly what was in the example code.

Answer (score 0):

My i know if you already deployed to a server which can be publicly accessed by Shopify?

It seems to me that you are doing locally and try verify oauth locally, i will auth right, but for redirection, if will fail for sure.

Comment: I've also tried deploying on heroku server, but still no luck. I cant understand why both the values ($signature and md5($signature_data)) are not same.

Answer (score 0):

Shopify requires that the app server be SSL protected. The Oauth will fail due to this. I banged my head on this one for a while. Some older docs and tutorials out there say you can test with localhost but this is not true any longer.

Comment: What is the solution now? Where do i test it now?

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I'm surprised Shopify is (still?) linking to that. That example code is all kinds of wrong.

The function returning the "request is NOT from Shopify" error is calculating the hmac code incorrectly. I've seen this in a couple of other libraries, especially ones maintained by people other than Shopify.

The parts for the hmac signature *must* be:

1. Obtained by *removing* the `hmac` and `signature` fields from the response data. (This is where this, and most third party libraries, get it wrong. They often build the fields the docs show as the remainder, but this is incorrect, because the docs don't show all of the fields that could be there, and the API can change without the docs being updated.)
2. Sorted alphabetically by key name (in PHP, this can be done with the `ksort()` function).
3. Special characters replaced with their query string coded values (ie - `%` becomes `%25`).
4. Turned into a query string. (In PHP: `http_build_query($toTest)`)
5. Hashed **per hmac standards** using sha256 and the shared secret. (`hash_hmac('sha256', $toTest, $secret);`)

Here's a working example for you:

```
public function verifyRequest($request, $secret) {
    // Per the Shopify docs:
    // Everything except hmac and signature...

    // Plain PHP, pass in $request as assoc array of all query string items
    $hmac = $request['hmac'];
    unset($request['hmac']);
    unset($request['signature']);
    $signature = $request;

    // Laravel or other framework with a first-class Request object
    // Use this or the unsets, above, not both
    $signature = $request->except(['hmac', 'signature']);



    // Sorted lexilogically...
    ksort($signature);

    // Special characters replaced...
    foreach ($signature as $k => $val) {
        $k = str_replace('%', '%25', $k);
        $k = str_replace('&', '%26', $k);
        $k = str_replace('=', '%3D', $k);
        $val = str_replace('%', '%25', $val);
        $val = str_replace('&', '%26', $val);
        $signature[$k] = $val;
    }

    // Hashed per hmac standards, using sha256 and the shared secret
    $test = hash_hmac('sha256', http_build_query($signature), $secret);

    // Verified when equal
    return $request->input('hmac') === $test; // Laravel/frameworked code
    return $hmac === $test; // Vanilla PHP/using the array unset block
}
```